# how to getch rawresults.zip in alm (performance)

Tags: rest, hp-quality-center

Is there any way to fetch `rawresults.zip` `/ results.zip` files of HP ALM (performance) using REST or OTA?

If so can any one please help me out. Also the server link  is with HTTPS.

Its like `https://****.saas.hp.com/qcbin/start_a.jsp`.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to have a little bit of success with this using the REST API. I used the following REST address to try and retrieve the entire results as a zip. I then used the ZIP file to try and process the results I wanted:

```
http://{server:port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/results/{file-id}/logical-storage/
```